# How to get locale in nextjs in document component?

Tags: next.js

I want to set the locale in the script google map like this:

```
<script defer src={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&libraries=places&language=${locale}`}/>
```

but how can I get to the locale in Document nextJS?
useRouter does not work in the Document component.

```
export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
       
      
<script defer src={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&libraries=places&language=${locale}`}/> 
      </Head>

      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access locale in `this.props.locale`.

In my project this locale uses in this case:

```
 <Html lang={this.props.locale}>
/....
```

I use class component in _document.

In your variant you can access locale just in props.

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default function Document(props: DocumentProps) {
  return (
    <Html lang={props.locale}>
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

It works if you already add i18n config, and inject it to next config.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/musing-noether-7loye1?file=%2Fpages%2F_document.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A9%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A11%2C%22startColumn%22%3A9%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A11%7D%5D